# How to activate the method to draw from a button?

Tags: android, onclick, draw, activation

I am fairly new to android. I have this code to draw in my app, but I want activate it with a button. If I click on action bar button I'll should draw, otherwise I will should't do it. How can I do it?

```
//DRAW
public class CustomView extends View {
    Bitmap mBitmap;
       Paint paint;
        Path path;
       public CustomView(Context context) {
           super(context);
      mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(640, 1024, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
           paint = new Paint();
                   path= new Path();
           paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
           //paint.setStyle(Style.FILL); //if I want to fill but I don't
           paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
           paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
       }

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    super.onDraw(canvas);
     canvas.drawPath(path,paint);
      canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 25, paint);
   }

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
       int action = event.getAction();
       switch (action){
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    path.moveTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
    path.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
     break;
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
       x = event.getX();
       y = event.getY();
       path.lineTo(x, y);
       invalidate();
     break;
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
       path.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
     break;
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
     break;
   default:
     break;}
       return true;
   }}


@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_edit:
                Log.i("ActionBar", "Edit");

// FROM HERE I WANT TO ACTIVATE

            return true;
        case R.id.menu_save:
            Log.i("ActionBar", "Guardar!");;
            return true; 
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

**Edit**: my application consists of text. And I want to let the user underline these text, and to do this you must first enable the touching a action bar button. And if you do not want to underline more, you click the button again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call invalidate() on the view you want to redraw

Comment: I used this code in swich to activate: layout=(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);
             layout.addView(new CustomView(Objeto.this));
             layout.invalidate();. Now I'll have to see how to disable it.Thanks Gabe.

Comment: Do you know how deactivate or stop onDraw when I click the button again? I don't find how do it.

Comment: If you want it to return to the previous state, you'll have to make it look at some boolean flag to determine whether to draw those things or not, and make your button toggle that flag then call invalidate.

Comment: Yes, I tried to do that but it didn't work. This is the code: case R.id.menu_edit:
             layout=(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);
             layout.addView(new CustomView(Objeto.this));
          if(activarLapiz==true){
             layout.invalidate();
             activarLapiz=false;
             }
          else{
              activarLapiz=true;}. What do you think? Thanks for the help

Comment: invalidate in both branches.

Comment: I also tried that, but still drawing. if(activarLapiz==true){
             layout.invalidate();
             activarLapiz=false;
             }
          else{
           layout.invalidate();
              activarLapiz=true;} :/

Comment: And is your onDraw checking the value of activarLapiz and not drawing the path and circle if its false?

Answer (score 0):

If I get what you mean you need to do some simple tasks.

First of all the OnDraw() method is called by its own so you can not execute an action manually if you this action in the onDraw() method. I would suggest creating a method that handles these actions. So try removing these 2 lines:

`canvas.drawPath(path,paint);
 canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 25, paint);`

Secondly, you have to add a `onClickListener` attached to the button you want to be responsible for these actions. If you don't know how to do this post me a question and I will create a tutorial here.
Id these does not work I would be grateful to help you with other solutions.

Comment: onDraw can be forced by invalidating the view.  And if he wants his ondraw to draw a circle and a path, that's the place he needs those lines.  I don't think you understood his question-  he wants to force a menu item to redraw his view.

Comment: I tried this but doesn't work: I created a method with canvas.drawPath(path,paint);
 canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 25, paint);
and I created a boolean that in onOptionsItemSelected method is true, then I should can draw, but I don't can. That's what you tell me to do? Sorry if my English is not very well